# Submitting a form after x amount of characters

Tags: jquery, forms, form-submit

I am creating a simple tool to use at my job, to create an unordered list of all EAN codes that are scanned. So far i have a working form that automatically submits after 12 characters have been entered in an input field. The problem however is that the scanner i use at my job, doesnt enter one character at a time into the input field, but it throws the entire bunch of characters into the field at once. This way the function to autosubmit after 12 characters doesnt work anymore, since it looks for a keydown.

Is there any possibility to make this work like i intend?

Here is the piece of jQuery i already have working.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#eanInput').keydown(function(){

    var vallength = $(this).val().length;

    if (vallength == 12){
        $('#eanForm').submit();
    }

});

$('#eanForm').on('submit', function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    $('#eanList').append('<li>' + $('#eanInput').val() + '</li>');

    $('#eanInput').val('');

});    });
```

And ofcourse a simple form called 'eanForm' with an inputfield called 'eanInput' and an unordered list called 'eanList'.

Comment: Have you tried using the `.change()` event?

Comment: Figure out which event is common between the two cases and bind to it, checking the length of the value each time said event happens. When it is 12, continue.

Comment: Note that it may also be an option to configure your scan gun to input just like the one at "your job". Most scan guns (all of the ones i've worked with) have a way of changing how the data is outputted.

Answer (score 1):

Just check after each change of the input control:

```
$('#eanInput').bind('change paste input blur', function(){
    var vallength = $(this).val().length;
    if (vallength == 12){
        $('#eanForm').submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: the `change` event will only be triggerred after losing focus

Answer (score 1):

Use `change` event instead as this will get fired even whenever value is changed.

```
$('#eanInput').change(function(){

    var vallength = $(this).val().length;

    if (vallength == 12){
        $('#eanForm').submit();
    }

});
```

Comment: For text input elements, the `change` event is deferred until the element loses focus, so the it's not fired *whenever value is changed* but *whenever value is changed after leaving focus*

Answer (score 1):

A barcode scanner usually trigger a **`paste` or `input` event** :

```
$('#eanInput').bind('paste input', function () {
});
```

And if that's not enough, you can also catch almost every available event to find the right one :

```
$('#eanInput').bind('DOMAttrModified textInput input change keypress paste focus', function () {
});
```

In response to the other answers, the **`change` event won't be triggered** until the input loses its focus.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i used the entire set of events as Zakinster suggested, and i changed the length == 12 to length >=12. Now it seems to be working like i want.

I want to thank you all for your quick responses. You people are the shiz.

<3